# How to send info in a form without redirecting user

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this form where  I send information to a page only admins should see so that they can chose to accept or not accept information to be put on a website. I am currently using `<form action="createp/confpage.php" method="post" >` to send information to this page with my form. Here is the button if this makes a difference too:`<button class="submitf">Create page</button>`. I guess what I am really trying to ask is, is it possible to send data from a form and the user to two separate pages? Thank you

Comment: You can have the target page redirect the user

Comment: Well send the form data to the confpage.php, and on the confpage.php header the user to where you want. And also instead of using button to submit form, use: <input type="submin" name="submit" value="Create page">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Jquery.Ajax, you can send the information to as many pages as you want.
for this you'll have to add an on click event for the button.

**HTML CODE**

```
<button class="submitf" onclick="Submit_OnClick">Create page</button>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function Submit_OnClick{
    data = {name:'Your Name', age:11};
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url2,
      data: data
    });
}
```

This will send post requests to 2 separate pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you know jquery, do this:

```
$.post("page1.php", $("#testform").serialize());
$.post("page2.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```

if you want a response do this:

```
$.post("page1.php", $("#testform").serialize()).done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
$.post("page2.php", $("#testform").serialize()).done(function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

To make your like easier from the answer use this. You will also need the onclick function as in Moiz Ahmed answer. Just not the ajax part of the function.